# Filing a motion/request with US federal court when one or more of the defendants were replaced since the original complaint

Tags: united-states, civil-law, civil-procedure, us-federal-government, federal-courts

A complaint was filed with a US federal court. If there is a need for the plaintiff to file a motion or request (e.g. a request for entry of default) related to the original complaint, the motion or request usually have to start with the same caption as the original complaint. I.e. it should list the same plaintiffs and defendants (and the case number) as in the caption of the original complaint.

What happens if one (or more) of the defendants, who is a US government official and is sued in his official capacity, has been replaced since the filing of the original compliant?

**For example:**

The original caption might have included:

> George Washington, President of the United States,
>
> Defendant

Now if since then George Washington has been replaced by John Adams who is now the incumbent President, and I would like to file a motion related to the original complaint, what would the caption on the motion look like?

Is it

> John Adams, President of the United States,
>
> Defendant

or (which may look like George Washington just changed his name to John Adams)

> John Adams (formerly George Washington), President of the United
> States,
>
> Defendant

or still

> George Washington, President of the United States,
>
> Defendant

or something else?

Comment: [FRCP Rule 25(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_25) seems relevant: "An action does not abate when a public officer who is a party in an official capacity dies, resigns, or otherwise ceases to hold office while the action is pending. The officer's successor is automatically substituted as a party. Later proceedings should be in the substituted party's name, but any misnomer not affecting the parties’ substantial rights must be disregarded. The court may order substitution at any time, but the absence of such an order does not affect the substitution."

Comment: The "Notes of Advisory Committee on Rules—1961 Amendment" further down has some more explanation.

Comment: By "substituted party's name" does it mean the person who was substituted (i.e. George Washington), or the (current) name of the party which was substituted (i.e. John Adams)?

Comment: It'd be the new party - Adams.  There are lots of examples of famous cases that are known by the name of a defendant who was not the original defendant; for instance, [*Gideon v. Wainwright*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gideon_v._Wainwright) was originally *Gideon v. Cochran*.  (Wainwright succeeded Cochran as Secretary of the Florida Department of Corrections.)  It also matches the usual English usage of "substitute", e.g. "Adams was substituted for Washington".  We'd say Washington was the person who was substituted *for*.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my OP. As for my follow up question, is it not correct to say that Washington is the former name of the party which was substituted, but Adams is the current name of the party which was substituted, therefore "the substituted party's name" may be ambiguous?

Comment: I would say that "the substituted party" unambiguously refers to Adams.  Adams was substituted for Washington, thus Adams is the party who was substituted, and Washington is the party who was substituted *for*.  The direct object of the verb "substitute" should be the replacement thing, not the old one.  Followups on that should probably go to English.SE instead.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification... it does change my understanding of the verb. I will post a question at the English Language forum as you suggested.

Comment: @rapt: Avoid using the phrase "former name of the party" unless you are talking about a *single* party who has changed their name. If there are two parties, "former name of the party" is ambiguous and confusing.

Comment: @Kevin I used "former name of the party which was substituted".

Comment: There's on the Wiktionary page for "substitute" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substitute a good explanation on how "to substitute" can be used in two opposite ways. See the "Usage notes": The verb "to substitute" can be used transitively in two opposite ways. "To substitute X" may mean either "use X in place of something else" (as in definitions 1 and 2), or "use something else in place of X" (as in definitions 3 and 4). The latter use is more recent, but it is widespread and now generally accepted (see the COED's note on the matter).

Comment: However, if the indirect object (the "something else") is omitted, the preposition is also omitted, and the reader or hearer cannot tell which sense is meant:

    "Substitute butter for olive oil" = Use butter instead of olive oil
    "Substitute butter with olive oil" = Use olive oil instead of butter
    "Substitute butter" = ???